# Audio Controller for Adobe Flash CC

Tags: adobe-flash

Hi im using adobe Flash CC 2014 and i want to have a audio controller. Im making and android App and when i import video i get the controller for video like this

[image]

And I need same controller (play, stop, pause, volume slider (increase / decrease) for audio. When i import audio file there is nothing to that.

How can i have a audio controller.

[image]

This type of audio controllers. Is there any ready made or action or plugin or addon to install and use. Like the video file its ready made just ask for the path to add and the controller are ready.

Is there any way to add. Any suggestion or help. Thanks